# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" When using PowerShell to run a working SSMS query

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ssms, powershell-5.1

Below is a working SSMS query, meaning it will run and produce the requested results in SSMS with no problems. But, I am trying to get this query to run in PowerShell in order to create a daily automated script. PowerShell simply puts the output of this SSMS query into an array, then transfers it to a .txt file. When it is run in PowerShell, it kicks back:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s)
"The multi-part identifier "l.cust_login" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "l.user_id" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "c.cust_full_name" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "a.login_type" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "a.flag_login" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "a1.flag_login" could not be bound"
"The multi-part identifier "a2.flag_login" could not be bound"
```

Here is the query that mind you, works in SSMS just fine!

```
    SELECT
    rtrim(l.cust_login)+':'+
    rtrim(l.user_id)+':'+
    rtrim(c.cust_full_name)+':'+
    rtrim(a.login_type)+':'+
    
    CASE
    WHEN a1.flag_login IS NOT NULL THEN 'flagged'
    ELSE ''
    END+':'+

    CASE
    WHEN a2.flag_login IS NOT NULL THEN 'co-flagged'
    ELSE ''
    END
    
    FROM accounts a
    INNER JOIN customer c ON a.owner_id = c.owner_id
    INNER JOIN logins l ON a.cust_login = l.cust_login

    --problematic joins
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts a1 ON (a.cust_login = a1.cust_login AND a1.flag_login = 22)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts a2 ON (a.cust_login = 
    a2.cust_login AND a2.flag_login IN (45,46))
    
    WHERE a.flag_login = 55
    ORDER BY 1
```

Now, ive been able to find where PowerShell gets upset, and its with the recursive table joins. If I leave them out, then the query runs fine in PowerShell. Below is an example query that I made that does not include the needed `JOINS` and `CASE`

```
    SELECT
    rtrim(l.cust_login)+':'+
    rtrim(l.user_id)+':'+
    rtrim(c.cust_full_name)+':'+
    rtrim(a.login_type)+':'
    
    --missing CASE statements here
    
    FROM accounts a
    INNER JOIN customer c ON a.owner_id = c.owner_id
    INNER JOIN logins l ON a.cust_login = l.cust_login
    
    --missing outer joins here
        
    WHERE a.flag_login = 55
    ORDER BY 1
```

I actually had the bright idea of converting the problematic query to include temp tables, I sadly have the same issue! Even when I define separate temp tables in place of the recursive joins. As well as CTEs!

I suppose my main question is, does anyone know a workaround that powershell may like for the problematic outer joins. As with the error, it seems as if powershell is having trouble distinguishing between `accounts a, accounts a1, and accounts a2`. Even though when ran solely in SSMS, there is no issue.

I know this is a lot, I added the powershell script due to request. Sorry for the long post.

**PowerShell SQL module:**

```
function Invoke-table1SQL {
    param ([string] $FileLocation)

    if (!(Test-Path $FileLocation)) {
        Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "File does not exist: $FileLocation"
        exit
    }

    $config_file = "$PSScriptRoot\ConnectionStrings.config"
    [xml] $appSettings = (Get-Content $config_file)
    $connectionString = $($appSettings.connectionStrings.add | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "ConnectionString" }).connectionString
    
    #db connection
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    
    #run sql cmd
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 1200
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = get-content $FileLocation
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    
    return $DataSet
}

export-modulemember -function Invoke-table1SQL
```

**And here is the actual script using the module:**

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Invoke-table1SQL.psm1 -Force

#declare
$queryLocation = "[location of query]"
$results = Invoke-table1SQL -FileLocation $queryLocation

#return index '0' in $dataset - $results and clean up output file
$outfile = "[txt file output location] " 
$results.Tables[0].Rows | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File -filePath $outfile
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: `b` is for customer when `c` is for Logins, for example, is *very* confusing. Why is `customer` not `c`? `l` would make much for sense for `logins`.

Comment: Your right, it is a bad, lazy habit...

Comment: As an aside, there's nothing *recursive* about joining to the same table twice with different criteria.

Comment: I'll bet the quotes in your SQL might be tripping up PowerShell's parser - or you need a `USE` statement, or your connection-string isn't using the correct `Initial Catalog=` parameter.

Comment: Does it work if you just remove all the `ELSE ''`?

Comment: @LukStorms Sadly that did not work.

Comment: @Larnu I fixed the lazy identifiers : )

Comment: @Stu The `ELSE` should handle any nulls I thought?

Comment: Can you provide the powershell script then?

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure about the quotes, as like I said, the second query that includes quotes works fine in powershell. Adding a `USE` (db name) at the top did not make a difference sadly.  The connection string is set to use the right database. I would expect the second query to not work either, if that was a problem.

Comment: One bad practice is that you aren't schema qualifying your tables so they could resolve to entirely different objects without the expected columns if run under a different user

Comment: @MartinSmith I can provide the script, one moment : )

Comment: I'm not a frequent powershell user but `$SqlCmd.CommandText = get-content $FileLocation` looks suspicious to me. The documentation says "For files, the content is read one line at a time and returns a collection of objects, each of which represents a line of content." so I am suspicious that the command text may just be set to the first such item (so truncating the query to before where those aliases are later introduced)

Comment: @MartinSmith Wow... I cannot thank you enough. You do not want to know how many days I have spent trying to figure out the issue. Too many days.... You were right, this was the issue. While I will spend some time looking around for a better alternative to `Get-Content`, for the time being I just replaced the entire query into powershell in `Get-Contents` and `$FileLocations` place to test, and it worked. Please go ahead and write on this post with your comment as an answer, so that I may mark it as the solution. I dont think I can mark comments as a solution.

Comment: I'll leave it to someone that knows the vagaries of powershell to provide a fuller answer

Comment: You can try passing `-Raw` to `Get-Content`  have it place the comments of the file in a scalar variable (instead of an array)

Comment: @BenThul Thanks, Adding `-raw` to `get-content` seems to work. Its a lot nicer than pasting the entire query into the script. I'm not too sure why adding that makes a difference. I suppose it reads the query as a whole now? Rather than line by line?

Comment: The documentation says as much: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the [dbatools](http://dbatools.io/github) module? They have an [Invoke-DbaQuery](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery) command that can run a query from the text file. I'd be curious if this worked as it is pretty robust.

Something like this maybe?

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance serverName -File $QuerySqlFile
```